# Does SalesForce store HTML version of email sent using 'Send an Email' button in activity history?

Tags: email, html, tasks

Whenever I send email using 'Send an Email' button in activity history section, SF allows me to format it like HTML email and user receives HTML formatted email as well. However, when I later want to see the email, its in plain text format only. Is there any setting for it or Salesforce doesn't store HTML version of email sent at all?!

[image]

Comment: You can create email templates .
we do have options for plain text, html, html with letterhead and visualforce email template<

Comment: @NickSFDC I do not have any problem sending html email. My problem is Salesforce stores only plain text email in Task record it created for that sent email. For example in attached image, I formatted that text bold/italics but SalesForce stored it in plain text format. Now if I later wanted to send same email, I have to go through all the formatting steps  again. Can we make SalesForce to store email in format it was sent?!